# What is the most efficient functional version of the following imperative code?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning Scala and I want to know the best way of expressing this imperative pattern using Scala's functional programming capabilities.

```
def f(l: List[Int]): Boolean = {
  for (e <- l) {
    if (test(e))
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

The best I can come up with is along the lines of:

```
l map { e => test(e) } contains true
```

But this is less efficient since it calls test() on each element, whereas the imperative version stops on the first element that satisfies test(). Is there a more idiomatic functional programming technique I can use to the same effect? The imperative version seems awkward in Scala.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the exists method:

```
val listWithEvens = List(1,2,3,4)
val listWithoutEvens = List(1,3,5)
def test(e: Int) = e % 2 == 0

listWithEvens.exists(test(_)) // true
listWithoutEvens.exists(test(_)) // false

// alternative
listWithEvens.exists(_ % 2 == 0)  // true
```

If you are not familiar with the _ used like this, it's the equivalent of:

```
listWithEvens.exists(v => v % 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

So, what you want is the `exists` method (`l.exists(test)`), which says nothing of how you'd *implement* it. The simplest implementation isn't very efficient:

```
def f(l: List[Int]): Boolean = l.foldLeft(false)((flag, n) => flag || test(n))
```

The problem is that it will iterate through all of `l`, even if the testing stops once `flag` becomes true. Now, most functional methods of iteration (in strict languages) will not stop iterating until finished through all the collection. The ones that do are actually implemented pretty much like you did, so, in the end, you are just hiding that sort of code, not avoiding it.

However, if I were required to use existing methods, and, of course, not to use `exists`, and be efficient on top of that, one could do something like this:

```
def f(l: List[Int]): Boolean = l.dropWhile(!test(_)).nonEmpty
```

Comment: I like the dropWhile example.

Comment: Of course, the Scala collections _do_ use an efficient implementation, so there is no need to resort to `dropWhile`.

Comment: @Aaron I did not mean to imply it wasn't. Bad wording on my part, specially at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it isn’t necessary in this case (and I actually expect the Scala library to use a more imperative version for their own `exists` – or at least have a `map` with an explicit `break` in it) but on a `List` you can use a simple (tail) recursive function.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def exists(l: List[Int], p: (Int) => Boolean): Boolean = l match {
  case Nil => false
  case x :: xs => p(x) || exists(xs, p)
}
```

Because `||` only evaluates the right side if the left side is `false` it means you break early.

This, of course, is only efficient if referencing the tail of a collection is cheap.

Comment: If you write this in terms of the `iterator` rather than `tail`, you'll get efficient tail recursion even on collections that do not have an efficient `tail` (which includes all of the mutable sequence types). Of course, with mutable iterators there's little to be gained over the imperative solution.